# How to display alert from ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to display alert from `ViewModel`.

problem: The name `DisplayAlert` does not exist in the current context

How to do that? Below is my code.

```
-- XAML
<Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" BackgroundColor="Green" TextColor="White" WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="60"  Text="Login" />


--- ViewModel :

class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
       

        private string _username;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }     
         }

        private string _password;

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public LoginViewModel()
        {          

        }

        public Command LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(ValidateUser);
            }

        }     

       async void ValidateUser()
        {
            if (_username.Length > 1 && _password.Length > 1)
            {
               //await DisplayAlert("Login", "Login Success", "Ok");
            //--Update:

                UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("Login Success", "Login", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
               // display invalid credential
            }
        }
```

**Update**
There are
a) Acr.UserDialogs V6.5.1
b) Acr.XamForms.UserDialog v5.0.0

I am using the older version which is (b) since I m using PCL .

I did import it and change the code to use it as above. But there is err msg:
using Acr.UserDialogs;

Err Msg:

```
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.FinishCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0004f] in <bd30a18775d94dc8b6263aecd1ca9077>:0 
  at Android.App.AlertDialog+Builder..ctor (Android.Content.Context context) [0x0007a] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at Acr.UserDialogs.Builders.AlertBuilder.Build (Android.App.Activity activity, Acr.UserDialogs.AlertConfig config) [0x0000d] in <addbf2648c204949b40c582bd49b7ddd>:0 
  at Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogsImpl.Alert (Acr.UserDialogs.AlertConfig config) [0x00038] in <addbf2648c204949b40c582bd49b7ddd>:0 
  at Acr.UserDialogs.AbstractUserDialogs.Alert (System.String message, System.String title, System.String okText) [0x00024] in <ec0104dbfc974343b668f7b28f49a1ab>:0 
  at BookingNow.ViewModel.LoginViewModel.ValidateUser () [0x00026] in C:\Users\Edward\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\BookingNow\BookingNow\BookingNow\ViewModel\LoginViewModel.cs:88 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:360)
    at md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:30)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18787)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Comment: The name 'DisplayAlert' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Can you share your stack trace when that happens? Also, `DisplayAlert` most likely is attached to the UI lifecycle so it cannot be directly called outside of a page (in your case, the ViewModel). A solution to this was provided [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22499/looking-to-pop-up-an-alert-like-displayalert-but-from-the-view-model-xamarin-forms-labs) using a pub/sub implementation.

Comment: If you use single activity ,maybe you can use
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(params)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep it pure, you should probably refrain from using alerts in the traditional way and find some way to collect input that you can trigger from toggling a property.

However, there is another, simpler way. You could use [ACR.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs). If you're not using .NET Standard yet you will need to install an older version of the NuGet package. Remember to install it in both your shared project as well as the platform projects. It might also need some initialization code depending on the platform, make sure to check the readme.

You can now either call the instance directly with: `UserDialogs.Instance` and then a method to show an alert or whatever you need. To keep it a bit more MVVM like you could also register this instance with it's interface counterpart and have it injected into your view models.

Comment: This works: await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login", "Login Success", "Ok");  But I dont have the MainPage.xaml in my project.I deleted it. Why this works??

Comment: `Application.Current.MainPage` does not point to a file or class called `MainPage`, it is a property of the `App` object and contains the page that is set as the main page of your application. So it can be any page.

Comment: I added it to all the Projects thru right click solution and add. It seems I got error when using it. Did i miss anything? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the [initialization code](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#android-initialization-in-your-main-activity) to your activity?

Comment: it Works!!!! Would like to know this: 1) Can this Application.Current.Main to display alert  be reliable to work just as good as Acr.UserDialog? Is this Older version Acr.UserDialog v5.0 is the ONLY version for PCL if I dont use .NetStandard. I will try seek your help on IOC for IDialogService in my future thread. Thank you so much.

Comment: 1) Acr.UserDialogs just calls the platforms native methods to show messageboxes, etc. so it is very reliable. 2) Yes, you cannot upgrade to a newer version without converting to .NET standard. I recommend to start new projects in .NET Standard. Please don't forget to accept this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis do you have a sample code to call it and show from ModelView?
I can call Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login", "Login Success", "Ok"); and works but
var dialog =  UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("dsa");
            dialog.Show();
doesn't from VM but works from Code Behind

Comment: Not sure what is going on there. But I don't see any await in there. Are you missing some async/await construction?

Comment: @MilkBottle Don't reference the app directly from your view model if possible, it is anti pattern.

Answer (score 26):

1. Create an interface:

```
public interface IMessageService
{
    Task ShowAsync(string message);
}
```

2. Implement the interface:

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    public async Task ShowAsync(string message)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("YourApp", message, "Ok");
    }
}
```

3. Inject the dependency service into App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        //Add the next line
        DependencyService.Register<ViewModels.Services.IMessageService, Views.Services.MessageService>();
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

4. Initialize it in your ViewModel and use:

```
public class YourViewModel 
{
    private readonly Services.IMessageService _messageService;

    public YourViewModel()
    {
        this._messageService = DependencyService.Get<Services.IMessageService>();

        //Show the dialog with next line
        _messageService.ShowAsync("Hi!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the Page to the ViewModel

In your view pass the page to the ViewModel with 'this'

```
public partial class ThePage : ContentPage
{

    ViewModel viewModel;

    public ThePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new ViewModel(this);
}
```

and then in your view model

```
public class ViewModel
{

    Page page;
    public ViewModel(Page page)
   {
     this.page = page;

     //SOME CODE 
    }

   async void ValidateUser()
    {
        await page.DisplayAlert("Alert from View Model", "", "Ok");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because the ViewModel loses the virtue of having a parameterless constructor...won't this generate an error in the end?

Comment: and now VM knows about V.  Isnt' that what we dont want?

Comment: A trouble in this case is cause when you create a view model you dont want to depends on view ... You want to create push, pop, delete them without lost information. 

I guess that If you depends on view to create the viewmodel is same that setup all code in view.

Comment: Actually works for me. I think this dependency is legit in this context but it would be better to use the MessagingCenter instead