# Missing default constructor for App1.Pages.SetPageDetail (Position 12:18)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've imported a solution I used to work on on another pc. However, On the new pc I keep getting the error
    "Position 12:18. Missing default constructor for 
    'App1.Pages.SetPageDetail'."

I'm not sure why I get this error now, and can't find any satisfactory solutions for it. I tried emptying my /bin and /obj folders, and tried downgrading Xamarin.Forms to 2.5. Both didn't work. Cleaning the solution and restarting VS2017 didn't do the trick either.

The project is Cross Platform, supporting Android and IOS. Packages used are Xamarin.Forms, SQLite-net-pcl, Cam.Plugin.Connectivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Pages.SetPage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App1.Pages">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <pages:SetPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:SetPageDetail />      <!--Goes wrong here-->
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Constructor:

```
public SetPageDetail(MasterDetailPage master)
    {
      Master = master;
      InitializeComponent();
      SetViewModel viewModel = new SetViewModel();
      BindingContext = viewModel;
      MyListView.RowHeight = 60;
      MyListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SetViewCell));
      MyListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
    }
```

I have some other errors as well regarding .dll's, (ResolveLibraryProjectImports task failed) but I expect them to disappear after this one is fixed. If not, I will create a separate question for them.

Comment: did you try adding a default constructor in SetPageDetail?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to include that, but yes it does. I've added it to the OP.

Comment: that is NOT a default constructor.  A default constructor has no parameters.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I added it, and everything works perfectly now. Strange I didn't have issues with this on the other computer tho

Comment: @JasperMW If have solved this problem,remember to post it as answer.*.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to @Jason. I thought any public  constructor was a default constructor, which was wrong.

The default constructor accepts no parameters, and since my function didn't have any, I got the above error.

Comment: If somebody got error because Injection Dependency then need register Services in app.xml like this: DependencyService.Register => https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615824/4654957