# Is it possible to popup DisplayPromptAsync from MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, popup

Been banging my head on this one for a minute and need to ask for assistance...Is it possible to popup DisplayPromptAsync from MVVM? I had all my code functioning just fine but some "obstacle" required me to finally move to MVVM to resolve; however I have 2 instances that I want to popup and prompt user for input that I then consume the values submitted. If I am reading documentation correctly DisplayPromptAsync can only be used in a Page? I certainly do not want to have to write separate pages that asks a question and user types a response to each. I cannot just use 1 Page and ask all three as user may only ever require 1 question to be asked. UI was so easy by popping up this having user answer and move on how to accomplish this feat.

Any thoughts?

TIA!
Rick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a reference to the current page

```
App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve that.

The first is pop up the alert by `App.Current.MainPage` as Jason mentioned in his answer:

```
public class myModel { 

    public myModel()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("title", "message");
    }
}
```

Another way is that you can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to notify the Page the pop up the alert.

In model:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, "showAlertNotify");
```

In page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage>(this, "showAlertNotify", (sender) =>
    {
        // Do something whenever the "showAlertNotify" message is received
        this.DisplayPromptAsync("title", "message");
    });
}
```

You can also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62615824/10539446) by using interface to perform action.